# Problemas con mostrando Arrays con foreach y .append() (JS y Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Quiero hacer que un array se muestre en dos diferentes columnas, pero un valor del array aparece dos veces, como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

"Agua de Pina" es el valor repetido.

El array es el siguiente:

```
var bebidas_1 = [
"Agua de Jamaica", 
"Agua de Limon", 
"Agua de Horchata",
"Agua de Pepino",
"Agua de Pina"
],
i=1;
```

Muestro el HTML:

```
<div id="bebidas-menu" class="d-flex justify-content-center"></div>
```

*d-flex hace que se vuelva flex-box*

Y para mostrar el array, utilizo un foreach, junto con un switch para determinar cada cuantos valores cada cambiará de columna, por eso el "i=1" del principio.
JS:

```
(function($){
  $(function(){
      bebidas_1.forEach(function(element){
          //la columna debe tener solo tres elementos, si llega a cuatro, empieza otra columna
          if(i==4){
              i=1;
          }
          switch(i){
                case 1:
                    $("#bebidas-menu").append("<div class='bebidas-col'><div class='bebidas-item text-dark'> <p>" + element + "</p></div>");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $(".bebidas-col").append("<div class='bebidas-item text-dark'> <p>" + element + "</p></div>");
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    $(".bebidas-col").append("<div class='bebidas-item text-dark'> <p>" + element + "</p></div></div>");
                    break;
          }//cierra switch
          console.log(element);
          i++;
      });//cierra foreach
});
```

Sin embargo, en la consola aparece correctamente el foreach, ya que no se repite ningún valor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en la ultima iteracion existen dos divs con clase `bebidas-col`, por eso te inserta dos veces el ultimo elemento.  si cambias tu condicion para que `i=2` funciona bien.

```js
var bebidas_1 = [
"Agua de Jamaica", 
"Agua de Limon", 
"Agua de Horchata",
"Agua de Pepino",
"Agua de Pina"
],
i=1;

$(function(){
      bebidas_1.forEach(function(element){
          //la columna debe tener solo tres elementos, si llega a cuatro, empieza otra columna
          if(i==4){
              i=1;
          }
          switch(i){
                case 1:
                    $("#bebidas-menu").append("<div class='bebidas-col'><div class='bebidas-item text-dark'> <p>" + element + "</p></div>");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $(".bebidas-col:last").append("<div class='bebidas-item text-dark'> <p>" + element + "</p></div>");
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    $(".bebidas-col:last").append("<div class='bebidas-item text-dark'> <p>" + element + "</p></div></div>");
                    break;
          }//cierra switch
          console.log(element);
          i++;
      });//cierra foreach
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bebidas-menu" class="d-flex justify-content-center"></div>
```

Comment: El problema es que se pierde el flex y se vuelve una sola columna. ¿Hay alguna manera para evitar que se pierda el flex?

Comment: Tienes razon, en ese caso es mejor usar el selector `:last` de jQuery.  Ya edite mi respuesta.